# Preventing Facebook Commnet to close commenting box

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

I have a website and I use Facebook comments box. The problem I am having is that facebook closes the commenting space after 6 or 7 commments are made (example http://www.fotokio.com/SDoV ). Comments are very important for my website and I want to have as many as posible without it closing the commenting space. Here is an example of a place where depsite of having a lot of comments the commenting space (box) is still open: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/472/

Thanks,
Juan

Comment: There’s a link saying _“Agregar un comentario”_ (_“Add a comment”_ in English) on the right side at the very top of the comment box plugin  – so your users just have to click on that, and they can comment. (If by any chance your users are to _st&%#d_ to figure that out, then maybe they shouldn’t comment on stuff anyways ;-))

Comment: I know they can add the comment but in UX terms having the box open is much more inviting to do so.